# Randomly shuffling an array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, random

What I need to do is randomly shuffle an array of 25 numbers

```
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).ToArray();
```

So that it still has all the numbers from 0 to 24 but in a random order.
What would be the simplest way to do it?

@edit;

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).OrderBy(c => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var random = new Random(); arr = arr.OrderBy(i => random.Next()).ToArray();`

Comment: Google "Fisher-Yates shuffle" for ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `OrderBy(c => rnd.Next())` like this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).OrderBy(c => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Visual won't run this for me. It underlines 'random' and says
'a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property'

Comment: @Ayukawa See my updated answer. I renamed the variable's name to `rnd `. Fixed and no should work. Try it.

Comment: I actually noticed the mistake and changed 'rnd' to 'random' in both cases, so that is not the problem.

Comment: I edited it, there's new code now

Comment: @Ayukawa OK. You should cut that two lines and paste them to the under of `InitializeComponent` method.

Comment: That gives me aa different error, though. Now I can't refer to the 'arr' in a button I try to make. I get 'the name 'arr' does not exist in current context'. @S.Akbari

Comment: @Ayukawa Change it like this: `Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] arr;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            arr = arr.OrderBy(c => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        }`

Comment: That worked. Thanks for help.